# Clearing out Deja-Dup backups from my Ubuntu One cloud?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, backup, cloud, deja-dup

So, I pretty much exclusively use Ubuntu One for Deja-Dup. I have 3 computers hooked into this system, but one of them I don't use anymore. And now my 5GB of storage has been filled up. I can't afford to buy more right now. I tried unlinking the deja-dup/cr-48 folder, (yes, that unused computer is a Cr-48) but that didn't free up any storage. How do I free up storage so that I can keep making backups?

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to https://one.ubuntu.com/
2) Login
3) Go to Files and Folders
4) Look for ~/dejadup/Cr-48
5) Delete this folder.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

And you will have to delete the files (just stop syncing will not free up space):

[image]

Comment: Again, tried that. Clicked "Stop syncing this folder". No space was freed up, and now I can't get at the files.

Comment: You should gain space when you delete something.

Comment: Nope. I clicked [this](http://i.imgur.com/kxYbX), and no space was freed up. At all.

Comment: That is the problem MowDownJoe, you really need to delete it. Just stop syncing will not free up space: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iHRQB.jpg

Comment: The "Stop syncing this folder" button is used to delete a synced folder in the cloud, so should update the quota (it isn't called delete, because it won't cause synchronised copies of the folder on your local system from being deleted).  If it hasn't, I suggest filing a support request at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/